# Angular 12: Console.log en main.js en lugar del archivo ts correspondiente

Tags: angular

Me he dado cuenta de que al levantar los proyectos con "ng serve" en angular 12, los console.log al verlos en la consola del navegador indican:

---->  main.js:1

Con las demás versiones de angular que he trabajado me indicaba el archivo ts en el que se estaba ejecutando. Por ejemplo:

----> app.component.ts:24

También he notado que al compilar con el ng serve para hacer los desarrollos tarda significativamente más tiempo con angular 12, que con las versiones anteriores. Entiendo que esto tiene algo  que ver con el ivy.

Si alguien entiende o sabe como solventar está cuestión se lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible que hayas dejado de generar los ficheros map, comprueba la configuración de angular (angular.json), deberías tener algo como:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": false,
    ...
  },
  "development": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionarlo siguiendo la recomendación de la [respuesta de Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/452568/250). Efectivamente, la propiedad `sourceMap` es la que estaba causando ese funcionamiento.

En mi angular.json no tenía:

```
"development": {
  ...
  "sourceMap": true,
  ...
}
```

Pero he añadido la opción así y ya puedo ver los console.log como antes.:

```
 "architect": {
   "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
     "options": {
       ...
       "sourceMap": true
     },
```